# Append/Merge Dataframe with LDA output

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, gensim

I'm working on an LDA model using `Gensim` and `spacy`.

Generically:

```
ldamodel = Lda(doc_term_matrix, num_topics=4, random_state = 100, update_every=3, chunksize = 50, id2word = dictionary, passes=100, alpha='auto')
ldamodel.print_topics(num_topics=4, num_words=6)
```

I'm at the point where I have some output and I'd like to append my original Dataframe (from which the text came from) with the topics and a percent contribution for each document.

The original df looks like this

```
id  group text
234 1     here is some text
837 7     here is some text
494 2     here is some text
223 1     here is some text
```

I do some standard preprocessing including lemmatization, removing stop words, etc. and then compute percent contributions for each document.

my output looks like this

```
   Document_No  Dominant_Topic  ...                                           Keywords Text
0            0             1.0  ...  RT, new, work, amp, year, today, people, look,...    0
1            1             0.0  ...  like, time, good, know, day, find, research, a...    1
2            2             1.0  ...  RT, new, work, amp, year, today, people, look,...    2
3            3             3.0  ...  study, t, change, use, want, Trump, love, stud...    3
4            4             3.0  ...  study, t, change, use, want, Trump, love, stud...    4
```

I thought I could just concat the 2 dfs back together like so:

```
results = pd.concat([df, results])
```

but when I do that the indices don't match and I'm left with a sort of Frankenstein df that looks like this

```
id  group text                Document_No  Dominant_Topic  ...                                           
NaN NaN   NaN                 0            1.0             ...
NaN NaN   NaN                 1            0.0             ...
494 2     here is some text   NaN          NaN             ...
223 1     here is some text   NaN          NaN             ...
```

Happy to post fuller code if that would be helpful, but I'm hoping someone just knows a better way to do this from same point as I might print topics.

Comment: What would be your reason to concatenate these two DFs, is there any relation between the rows regarding the kind of contents?

Comment: @RuthgerRighart yes - so, I'd like to be able to look at a specific document (e.g. row of text) and see the topic breakdown for that row. In addition I'd like to be able to look at the topic breakdown by `group` a variable only in my original df.

Comment: you could use something like `pd.merge(df, results, left_index=True, right_index=True)`. In this case it will merge on index, even if the rows do not have any correspondence (that is, row 1 of df has nothing special with row1 in results), but it removes your NANs.

Comment: @RuthgerRighart so that approach doesn't truly merge the datasets, just shoves them together without any matching at all?

Comment: indeed, it only merges on index.